# how to exclude digits using regular expression in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

Hello I need to exclude sequence of digits from 890000 till 890001;

890002 to 899999 is acceptable

Is it possible doing using regular expression?

Comment: Do you want to remove every number in a given sentence? Can you add an example of what you want to do?

Comment: In regex, you normally specify what you want, not what don't want, so just create a regex that matches from '890002' to '899999'. BTW why don't you simply compare them as numbers?

Comment: @EricLozano,   is it possible to create a regular expression for whole range 89XXXX and exclude values from 890000 to 890001 ?   I use in in string ExcludedVariable = "89000[0-1]*"     , but how to build for rest range with exception?

Comment: @PoulBak Can you advice how to do it in this example?

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex.

```vb
If Value >= 890002 And Value <= 899999 Then
    ' Accept
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you insist on using regex (may be for learning purpose):

In this simple case it is actually easier to exclude those two number and match the rest:

```
^89(?!000[12])\d{4}$
```

**Explanation**:

`^` match from start of text

`89`match `89`

`(?!000[12])` negative look ahead for 3 times zero and one of characters in the character group (`1` or `2`). If this doesn't block the match:

`\d{4}` match 4 digits

`$` match end of text.